# Is it possible to run a for loop in bash that iterates through multiple targets?

Tags: bash, for-loop

Is it possible to run a for loop in bash that iterates through multiple targets? Or do I need to resort to nested for loops?

For example:

```
for i in *.config,*.command; do
  echo "Do something"
done
```

Thanks.

Comment: If your intent there was to iterate through files named \*.config and \*.command, yes, it will work, but only if you remove the comma and replace it with a space. (The list is space-delimited.) However, if, for example, there are no xxxx.config files i will be set to "*.config" unless you do `shopt -s nullglob` first. (Or `shopt -s failglob` if you want to have it generate an error.)

Comment: What do you mean by "iterating through multiple targets"? Targets are usually a `make` thing. The shell deals with commands and arguments.

Comment: By targets I meant .command, .config, .whatever files. I wasn't sure of a way to better convey the nature of my question. If I used the term "arguments" I think people would have been confused with the i iterator and not the actual targets (.config, .command).  Your solution worked, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this? It is not quite clear what you want to achive. Can you spell out which commands you want to run with which config files or arguments?

```
for i in *.config *.command; do
  echo "Do something to $i"
done
```

(Note: no comma!)

Comment: Awesome! Removing the comma was the best and sort of embarrassing solution. Thanks!

Comment: *Expert*, n.: someone who, in a small field, has made every mistake. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let file globbing expand inside an array declaration.

```
$ touch {1..5}.txt
$ touch {1..5}.cfg

# use nullglob
$ shopt -s nullglob

$ list=(*.txt *.cfg)

# loop over all elements in array
$ for file in "${list[@]}"; do echo "$file"; done
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
5.txt
1.cfg
2.cfg
3.cfg
4.cfg
5.cfg

# number of items
$ echo "${#list[@]}"
10
```

See [nullglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob)

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
for i in `ls *.config *.command` 
do
  echo "hhhh"
done
```

Comment: What's the point of using `ls` here? The shell does globbing without forking to `ls` without wasting precious CPU cycles.

Comment: The backquote ` is used in the old-style command substitution. The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside `$()` is less surprising, and is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: And you won the [useless use of ls award](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#ls)

Comment: i mean that he can any command in loop (as if he need more complicated command ) just to introduce concept